# Identify Assembly dll method invocations

Tags: dll, odbc, .net-assembly

I have a problematic win32 program that I only have the executable for. This program uses the ODBC32.dll. I am trying to figure out how this program sets up it's ODBC connection. More specifically if it is defining a timeout for command execution or not.

It seems reasonable to find this information by examining the assembly. Anyone know of any techniques for isolating calls to a dll within an assembly file?

I also have the pdb (debug symbols) for the exe if that helps.

Comment: http://www.dependencywalker.com/ Looks like it might help.

Comment: Do you just need a copy of the connection string, or are you after deeper analysis? For the former, a debugger and a breakpoint in the `SQLConnect` is all you need.

Comment: Worried that there may be a timeout being set using SQLSetStmtAttr... unsure, really this whole task is just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Search the Net for API tracing programs, execute it under one, and watch calls to `SQLSetStmtAttr`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Both good suggestions. Going to drop this task though.